# Magento2.3 : How do I programmatically submit a form generated via a UIComponent?

Tags: php, javascript, magento2.3, uicomponent, ui-form

I created a UI Component form, but I am unable to find the  element in the source.

I would like to click a button and then inspect a field in the form and dependent on what value is selected submit the form to a specific url.

In my uiComponent I have,

```
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">            
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/ui/form/new_form</item>
    </item>
```

Then I have the following code in Vendor_Module/js/ui/form/new_form:

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'mage/url'
],
function ($, form, url) {
    'use strict';

    return form.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            $('#new_button').click(this.new_button);

            return this;
        },
        new_button: function (redirect, data) {
            this.validate();

            if (!this.additionalInvalid && !this.source.get('params.invalid')) {

                // CUSTOM CODE HERE BEFORE SUBMIT

                this.setAdditionalData(data)
                    .submit(redirect);
            } else {
                this.focusInvalid();
            }
        }
```

I am currently getting,

> Uncaught TypeError: this.validate is not a function

Comment: Can you please paste your code here? Thanks

Comment: @Shankar I have added the code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to submit the form programmatically

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
        'mage/url'
    ],
    function ($, form, url) {
        'use strict';

        return form.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                var self = this;
                 $('#new_button').click(function () {
                    self.submit(self.source.submit_url);
                });
                return this;
            },
        })
    }
);
```